# Where can I best ask a question regarding trading cards?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I do not know where to ask the following question:

> What do you call a specific type of trading cards, which show a different image depending on the angle you look at it?

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for the word [holographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography). I'm almost inclined to say the question isn't about trading cards, but rather a [word request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-request), so an English language question.

---

That said, questions about trading card games like [Magic: The Gathering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering) are on-topic on [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange. This would work if you think these cards have a special name like ["foil / premium cards"](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Foil_card). As always, please check their [help center](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question.